# Errors when generating Release APK. Error: Duplicate resources; AAPT: error: resource string/app_name not found

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I'm just starting with React-Native. I'm using Atom as an editor with Genymotion for Emulator. The code is working very well. But it's I get stuck when is about generating Release APK.

I follow the tutorial from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android but I had some errors.

After some research I ran these commands

```
- react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
- cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

But I got many errors.

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :realm:forwardDebugPort
adb: error: no devices/emulators found
===========================================================================
WARNING: Failed to automatically forward port 8083.
In order to use Realm in Chrome debugging mode, port 8083 must be forwarded
from localhost to the device or emulator being used to run the application.
You may need to add the appropriate flags to the command that failed:
    adb forward tcp:8083 tcp:8083
===========================================================================


> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
info Writing bundle output to:, /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
info Done writing bundle output
info Copying 6 asset files
info Done copying assets

> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
[drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png    [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask.png        [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png        [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png      [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png  [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png        [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png  [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask.png      [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png      [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png    [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png        [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png      [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7m 0s
67 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 63 up-to-date
```

Some research show me that I must empty the **res** folder, what I did but after running `./gradlew assembleRelease` I got another errors

```
> Task :react-native-dialogs:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/node_modules/react-native-dialogs/android/src/main/java/com/aakashns/reactnativedialogs/modules/DialogAndroid.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-fs:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/node_modules/react-native-fs/android/src/main/java/com/rnfs/RNFSManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :realm:forwardDebugPort
adb: error: no devices/emulators found
===========================================================================
WARNING: Failed to automatically forward port 8083.
In order to use Realm in Chrome debugging mode, port 8083 must be forwarded
from localhost to the device or emulator being used to run the application.
You may need to add the appropriate flags to the command that failed:
    adb forward tcp:8083 tcp:8083
===========================================================================


> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
info Writing bundle output to:, /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
info Done writing bundle output
info Copying 6 asset files
info Done copying assets

> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:15: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.asqquestionnaire:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

  /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:15: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.asqquestionnaire:string/app_name) not found.

  /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:15: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.asqquestionnaire:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.

  /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:15: AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.asqquestionnaire:style/AppTheme) not found.

  /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:23: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.asqquestionnaire:string/app_name) not found.

  error: failed processing manifest.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3m 10s
70 actionable tasks: 64 executed, 6 up-to-date
```

I expect to have an APK after doing the configuration from Facebook React-native website. Do know what is going wrong.

I dont know how to workaround this problem.
Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, Its duplicate resource error.

See ,

```
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
[drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png    [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask.png        [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png        [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png      [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png  [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png        [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon] /home/maelfosso/Documents/Projects/Apps/Guitou/Customers/jnadia40/ASQQuestionnaire/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
```

These are the two same resources in normal `drawable` folder and other in `build/generated/res/react/release` folder.

remove these six file from `drawable` and it will work fine.

Comment: As I say I did it in my post. I delete everything from **android/app/src/main/res**
But I got another error about not founding **app_name**

Comment: you need to delete just duplicate resources not everything.

Comment: for aapt error, have you generated png files from jpg file?

Comment: No. Don't remember I did something like this

Answer (score 0):

Delete

```
/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon

/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backiconmask

/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon

/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon

/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon

/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon
```

if still error present after deletion delete all drawable folders

Comment: I just did it. But now as I said in my post, I'm getting now a new error about 
AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.asqquestionnaire:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found
AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.asqquestionnaire:string/app_name) not found

AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.asqquestionnaire:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found

AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.asqquestionnaire:style/AppTheme) not found

AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.asqquestionnaire:string/app_name) not found

Answer (score 0):

delete build folder android/app/build and android/build
check any duplication left in drawables if any delete that then
Commands:
1) react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
2) ./gradlew clean
3) ./gradlew assembleRelease

Replace 2 and 3 Command by attaching mobile to pc (can be a simulator) and then use the command 
react-native run-android --variant=release
this will run release in android mobile directly

Comment: I just did it but I got the second  error I described up there, in my post, about app_name not found.

Comment: @MaelElvisFosso check res->value->string file for the check if there is any app name like this <string name="app_name">Music Player Codelab</string>